# Cannot Start SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

That's the first time I use SSRS so my apologies if I'm asking something stupid.

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 already installed with SSRS. When I try to start the SQL Server Reporting Service I receive this error:

> System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: Time out has expired and the
>   operation has not been completed.    at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus
>   desiredStatus, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   ReportServicesConfigUI.Panels.ServerInformationPanel.StartStopServiceTask(Boolean
>   start)

Can someone help me with this issue? Which tests cna I do in order to debug/fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your event log to see if there is any additional information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open sql configuration manager, right click the Reporting Services service, go to properties, then advanced you should see an option to turn on error reporting.

It will also have the dump directory location. Check the latest log in there and it should tell you why it couldnt start.

Comment: The Errors I can see in the log:ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

Comment: Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Comment: Hmm, I'd make sure your using a good service account at that point. Also verify you can connect to the instance with SSMS